# Why my Jquery Autocomplete is not working with Mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code

The Function.js file

```
$(function() {
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( ".country_suggestion" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/suggestion.php",
                    data:'term='+request.term,
                    success: function(r){

                        return  r;
                        //response(r);
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                    }
                });
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term

            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

In PHP file

```
<?php


include('inc/safePDO.class.php');
include('inc/config.php');
$dbh = new 



  SafePDO('mysql:host='.$db['host'].';
dbname='.$db['name'].';charset=UTF8', $db['user'], $db['password']);

$term = $_POST['term'];

$list = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ((
                      SELECT `id`, `label` as name, CHAR_LENGTH(`label`) as name_length FROM `country`
                      WHERE `label` LIKE :name
                     ) UNION ( 
                      SELECT `id`, `label` as name, CHAR_LENGTH(`label`) as name_length FROM `countryregion`
                      WHERE `label` LIKE :name
                     )) as t
                     GROUP BY `name`
                     ORDER BY name_length ASC
                     LIMIT 0, 10");

$list->execute(array(':name' => "%{$term}%"));

$country_list = $list->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


$country = array();
foreach($country_list as $country_region_list) {
$country[] = $country_region_list->name;
}
//print_r($country_list);
echo json_encode($country);
```

i tried mostly all way by searching on google but not getting the result.

i'm getting the data from the db as in sorted form but the only thing is not working is popup.. the aucomplete popup is not showing...

if i print alert in success of ajax its showing the the shorted data but after that what to do i dont know... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PDO doesn't allow multiple placeholders, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244086/why-pdo-doesnt-allow-multiple-placeholders-with-the-same-name)

You may change your code renaming the parameters without duplicates:

```
$list = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ((
                  SELECT `id`, `label` as name, CHAR_LENGTH(`label`) as name_length FROM `country`
                  WHERE `label` LIKE :name1
                 ) UNION ( 
                  SELECT `id`, `label` as name, CHAR_LENGTH(`label`) as name_length FROM `countryregion`
                  WHERE `label` LIKE :name2
                 )) as t
                 GROUP BY `name`
                 ORDER BY name_length ASC
                 LIMIT 0, 10");

$list->execute(array(':name1' => "%{$term}%",':name2' => "%{$term}%"));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I got it error ...actually I already got data and it is working but main error is when ajax got data then it is not showing a just simple error that I have to parse JSON that's it.