# pdo query on duplicate update, then two delete's error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Trying to do an SQL query, on duplicate update and delete from two tables.

1. This works but only the first Delete from not, the second one is ignored.

   ```
   $sqlSalesOrderUpdate = $handler->prepare("
   INSERT INTO tv_sales_orders (sales_order_id, order_number) 
   VALUES (:sales_order_id, :order_number)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
   UPDATE sales_order_id=:sales_order_id;
   DELETE FROM `tv_sales_orders_lines` WHERE sales_order_id=:sales_order_id;
   DELETE FROM `tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines` WHERE 
   tv_sales_order=:sales_order_id;
                                   ") ;
   ```
2. With an join, it says:

   > exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\php\index.php:4882 Stack trace: #0

   ```
   $sqlSalesOrderUpdate = $handler->prepare("
   INSERT INTO tv_sales_orders (sales_order_id, order_number) 
   VALUES (:sales_order_id, :order_number)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
   UPDATE sales_order_id=:sales_order_id;
   DELETE FROM `tv_sales_orders_lines` WHERE sales_order_id=:sales_order_id;
   DELETE a.*, b.* 
   FROM tv_sales_orders_lines as a, tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines as b 
   WHERE a.sales_order_id =:sales_orders_id and b.tv_sales_order_id=:sales_orders_id ;
   ```

Comment: You normally cannot have multiple `:sales_order_id` placeholders in one query. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244086/why-pdo-doesnt-allow-multiple-placeholders-with-the-same-name

Comment: Whats the way around this?

Comment: Have you read the question in the link I gave? It tells you.

Comment: Thanks, I see I have to add PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES ON? but I don't understand where? in here? $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The best solution is the obvious one, use different placeholders: `:sales_order_id1`, `:sales_order_id2`, `:sales_order_id3`, etc.