# Problem converting mysqli to PDO | PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am currently converting my mySQLi PHP code into PDO for better security and I am having some trouble understanding how I can convert the code below and implement it into my new PDO PHP

The code below should take the last inserted ID (the one the PDO is inserting) and set the column idnum equal to the NUM(and the last inserted id).

How can this be converted and added to the PDO?

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $sql = "UPDATE Equipment SET idnum = CONCAT('NUM', '$last_id') WHERE equipment_id = '$last_id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I would like to add the code to the following PDO PHP script:

```
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'dbname';
$userdb = 'userdb';
$passdb = 'passdb';
$charset = 'utf8'; 

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['place'], $_POST['person'] , $_POST['number'] , $_POST['other_name'])) {
    // Connect and create the PDO object
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);


    $stmt = $conn->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `Table1` (name, place, person, number, other_name, progress)
VALUES (:name,:place,:person,:number,:other_name, "Done") ' );


    $stmt->execute([
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'place' => $_POST['place'],
        'person' => $_POST['person'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'other_name' => $_POST['other_name'],
    ]);

    // Shows the number of affected rows
    echo 'Affected rows : '. $stmt->rowCount();

}
```

Comment: If you're looking for the PDO equivalent of `mysqli_insert_id($conn)`, you want [`$conn->lastInsertId()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Then you can just execute the UPDATE query like you would normally do.

Comment: Well your missing a quote right here `$userdb = 'userdb;` but I assume that is just a typo in the question.  `would like to add the code to the following PDO PHP script`  The PDO is completely different, it's an insert and the other is an Update, how should we just add that to the insert.

Comment: `$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();` Then `$conn->prepare("UPDATE Equipment SET idnum = CONCAT('NUM', :last_id_0) WHERE equipment_id = :last_id_1")->execute(['last_id_0' => $last_id,
            'last_id_1' => $last_id
        ])';`  Keys/Placeholders have to be unique.  But if they are together, I would use a transaction and a try catch block too :-/

Comment: Why do you think PDO will give you better security? It's prepared statements that will give you better security and you can use those with `mysqli_*()`

Answer (score 1):

Like this I guess (if you want them combined):

```
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'dbname';
$userdb = 'userdb';
$passdb = 'passdb';
$charset = 'utf8'; 

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['place'], $_POST['person'] , $_POST['number'] , $_POST['other_name']  )) {
    // Connect and create the PDO object
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);

    try{
        //start a transaction {ACID}
        $conn->beginTransaction();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `Table1` (`name`, `place`, `person`, `number`, `other_name`, `progress`)
    VALUES (:name,:place,:person,:number,:other_name, "Done") ' );

        $stmt->execute([
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'place' => $_POST['place'],
            'person' => $_POST['person'],
            'number' => $_POST['number'],
            'other_name' => $_POST['other_name'],
        ]);

        //get the last insert ID
        $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `Equipment` SET `idnum` = CONCAT("NUM", :last_id_0) WHERE `equipment_id` = :last_id_1');
        //named placeholders must be unique
        $stmt->execute([
            'last_id_0' => $last_id,
            'last_id_1' => $last_id
        ]);
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;

        //commit the changes
        $conn->commit();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        //roll back the changes on errors
        $conn->rollback();
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Shows the number of affected rows this is pointless (for insert 1 row it's always 1 or an error)
    //echo 'Affected rows : '. $stmt->rowCount();

}
```

Transactions are like changing the DB for pretend (if it's INNODB table), then if there is an error with one of the query both fail.

It's advisable to use them when creating related records that way you don't leave orphan records or rows without the relationship just hanging around.

Comment: Any reason you're doing `last_id_0` and `last_id_1`

Comment: Because you cannot use the same named placeholder 2x.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244086/why-pdo-doesnt-allow-multiple-placeholders-with-the-same-name  With Prepare emulation `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` you cannot use the same placeholder more then once.  You can name it something else, I'm just lazy.  In other words you cannot use `:last_id` twice, just the way it is...